# InputPane.Showing/Hiding never called

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to do some smart resizing of XAML elements when the software keyboard is opened in my WP8 app, and for some reason the InputPane.Showing/Hiding events are never getting called.  Inside my `OnNavigatedTo` override, I have the following:

```
InputPane inputPane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
inputPane.Showing += (InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args) =>
{
    outputTextScroller.Height -= args.OccludedRect.Height;
};

inputPane.Hiding += (InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args) =>
{
    outputTextScroller.Height += args.OccludedRect.Height;
};
```

Putting breakpoints into the lambda expressions, I find that the code is never getting called.  No exceptions are being thrown, and nothing else in the app seems to be malfunctioning.  Does anyone know why these events would not be being triggered?  The input pane is opened either when I tap a TextBox for data entry, or tap a TextBlock which then focuses the TextBox for that data entry.

Comment: Did you find any solution for getting the keyboard height?

Answer (score 2):

I've added a bug report on Microsoft Connect, please upvote it if you are also interested in solving this issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814487/allow-inputpane-events-to-be-triggered-in-non-native-windows-phone-8-applications

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [InputPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx) states that it is only supported "native apps only". In order to determine when the virtual keyboard is shown, you need to handle the [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) events.

Comment: Are you able to show how to handle the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events, what type of object should I be handling these events on because they dont exist on `inputpane`